# How to identify if ADFS 1 server is using WS-Fed?

Tags: adfs

I have a Windows 2003 server running ADFS 1 (SAML 1.1) and I'm trying to determine if this system is using WS-Fed.

I do see `<wsa:....>` related items in the SAML communication both inbound and outbound. Not sure if "wsa" is a WS-Fed identifier though.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

AD FS 1 cant do anything else other than ws-fed. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755828(v=WS.10).aspx.